# How to ask forgiveness for the sin of your inner mind?

Tags: allah

I have no control over my mind.I often think bad about people. One of my cousin suffered from divorce.I moke her in my mind.  I want to ask forgiveness for this. I don't want to suffer from the same thing. Please tell me what to do?

Answer (score 1):

As long as these thoughts don't translate into prohibited sayings or actions, In Shaa' Allah you are not sinful for this..

> It is narrated on the authority of Abu Huraira that the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said :
>
> **Verily Allah forgave my people the evil promptings which arise within their hearts as long as they did not speak about them or did not act upon them.** [Sahih Muslim : 127]

I think they're just thoughts from shaitan to make you feel sinful, or feel bad about yourself

So, just kick these thoughts out of your mind, and dont go on with it.